# In Flex 4, state transition doesn't resize in both directions

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, state, transition

I have two states. When I switch from OFF to A, it resizes correctly, but when I switch from A back to OFF it happens without the smooth resize transition. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:VGroup xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

  <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      protected function butA_changeHandler(e:Event):void
      {       
        if ((e.target as ToggleButton).selected) {
          this.currentState="A";
        } else {
          this.currentState="off";
        }
      }
    ]]>
  </fx:Script>

  <s:states>
    <s:State name="off" />
    <s:State name="A" />
  </s:states>

  <s:transitions>
    <s:Transition fromState="off" toState="A" autoReverse="true">
      <s:Parallel duration="300">
        <s:Resize target="{content}" heightTo="{cA.height}" />
        <s:Fade targets="{cA}"/>
      </s:Parallel>
    </s:Transition>
    <s:Transition fromState="A" toState="off" autoReverse="true">
      <s:Parallel duration="300">
        <s:Resize target="{content}" heightTo="0" />
        <s:Fade targets="{cA}"/>
      </s:Parallel>
    </s:Transition>
  </s:transitions>

  <s:Group id="content" excludeFrom="off" width="100%" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">   
    <s:Group id="cA" includeIn="A" width="100%"><s:Label fontSize="70" text="A"/></s:Group>
  </s:Group>

  <s:HGroup>
    <s:ToggleButton id="butA" label="A" change="butA_changeHandler(event)"/>
  </s:HGroup>

</s:VGroup>
```

Thanks in advance,
Nuno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using both AddAction and RemoveAction as the includeIn and excludeFrom properties are processed before transitions:
.

```
<s:transitions>
        <s:Transition fromState="off" toState="A" autoReverse="true">
            <s:Sequence>
                <s:AddAction target="{content}" />
                <s:Parallel duration="300">
                    <s:Resize target="{content}" heightTo="{cA.height}" />
                    <s:Fade targets="{cA}"/>
                </s:Parallel>
            </s:Sequence>

        </s:Transition>
        <s:Transition fromState="A" toState="off" autoReverse="true">
            <s:Sequence>
                <s:Parallel duration="300">
                    <s:Resize target="{content}" heightTo="0" />
                    <s:Fade targets="{cA}"/>
                </s:Parallel>
                <s:RemoveAction target="{content}" />
            </s:Sequence>
        </s:Transition>
    </s:transitions>

    <s:Group id="content" width="100%" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">   
        <s:Group id="cA" includeIn="A" width="100%"><s:Label fontSize="70" text="A"/></s:Group>
    </s:Group>
```

Start the resizes off from the dimensions you want using heightFrom and widthFrom so that they actually animate.

*Note: Using an includeIn="A" means you are also implying that conent will have the excludeFrom="OFF" property.  This means you won't be able to mix Add/RemoveAction and includeIn/excludeFrom (one for adding views and another for removing them).

Comment: Hello Kevin, thank you so much! It worked like a charm. Nevertheless, to be honest, even though I already read about it in Adobe Flex documentation, I still didn't quite understand the need for AddAction/RemoveAction :-( If you care to explain I will be most grateful. Thanks! Nuno

Comment: So you mean I cannot use addAction/removeAction with a target which uses includeIn/excludeFrom? That's confusing because, even though the example doesn't have that, that's exactly what I need in my real life situation.

Comment: AddAction/RemoveAction and includeIn/excludeFrom are both doing the same thing - adding/removing display objects to/from parent containers that are already on the display list. The issue is that you want to use a transition to trigger an animation on display objects that were just removed from the display list via an excludeFrom.  The sequence you previously had:

state change -> includeFrom/excludeFrom's processed -> transition processed

You could play the animation first manually, then change the viewstate to fix the problem:

manually play animation w/o add/remove actions -> state change

Comment: I just created a new question with the example which still doesn't work (since I now don't have a component inside another): [here is the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555594/in-flex-4-state-transition-doesnt-resize-in-both-directions-v2). I tried to apply what you just explained but still without success...

Answer (score 1):

`autoreverse`set to true must be redundant with your second transition. It already defines A to off. Just add a `heightFrom`in the first transition.

Comment: Hi Kodiak,  Thanks. I added `heightFrom` in the first transition and removed `autoreverse`. I even added `heightTo`in the second transition. But still no success.  I heard maybe I needed `<s:AddAction>` in the transition but I don't understand how to use it.

Comment: Actually I was thinking about leaving `autoreverse` and removing the second transition ;) `AddAction` is linked to `AddChild` which you're not using here.

Comment: I just tried that and it also didn't work. Actually what I want to build has several states: A, B, C, D. So I expected to have several transitions `(* to A)`, `(* to B)`, `(* to C)` and then `(* to OFF)`. I have a working example which works fine switching between A, B and C. The problem occurs when I switch back to OFF. Would using `AddChild` make any sense?

Comment: I think you don't need `AddChild` which is sooo Flex 3 since you're using `excludeFrom` :) Sorry if I can't help much more...